# "Ubuntu" kernel version - what does it mean?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, linux

I have a 4.0.3 tablet (Genesis GT 1230 running some preinstalled rooted custom rom from factory). It reports its kernel as "3.0.8+ root@ubuntu #412".

Why "ubuntu"? What does it mean? Do I have Ubuntu on my Android tablet? Is it any different from an ordinary Android?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string "3.0.8+ root@ubuntu #412" is the *Kernel version* of your Android. It doesn't mean your device is running Ubuntu, though: It's not unusual that the kernel version includes the name of the machine it was compiled on. So it just tells you what the dev of your custom ROM uses for development.

Comment: Does it mean it runs a non-standard Android kernel? Or a non-standard Linux kernel? My Defy running CM9 shows a different string (I don't have it with me right now).

Comment: It just means it runs this specific kernel. ROM-builder might decide to place an optimized kernel into their ROM, and often they do. Of course there are also custom ROMS which are just modified stock ROMs, and the devs might decide to keep the original kernel. For sure it's nothing to worry about ;)

Comment: Its an identifier that identifies the host machine in which the kernel was compiled on and built. Nothing more, on my custom rom it shows 't0mm13b@riviera' which tells that the build was built on my local machine named (usually by the `hostname`) called 'riviera'. That does not mean to say, its a "non-standard Android kernel" nor a "non-standard Linux kernel", the version string 3.0.8 indicates the version that came form the mainline kernel source... :)

Comment: Ruda: Android is distributed in the form of source code, i.e. the device makers get it from chipset makers (like Qualcomm) which in turn got it from Google (https://android.googlesource.com/). There's no central authority that issues binary releases. Each hardware manufacturer compiles it's own kernel (and also the complete Android distribution) for each and every device model they make. How should it else work, that there are the platforms MIPS, x86, ARM, and ARM64 (future)? MIPS isn't even officially supported but there are devices out there nevertheless. Running Java Apps this is possible.